# Prove that Cauchy principal value of $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+2}dx=\frac{π\text{erfi}{2}}{e^4}$

Tags: integration, closed-form, cauchy-principal-value

Prove that :

$$PV\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x+2}dx=\frac{π\text{erfi}{2}}{e^4}$$

I know that for  $a \le p \le b$

$$PV\int_{[a,b]}f(x)dx =\lim_{t\to 0^+} \left(\int_{[a,c-p]}f(x)dx+\int_{[c+p,b]}f(x)dx \right)$$

I think I should use the series expansion of

$$\frac{1}{x+2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

But I don't know how I find

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^{n}e^{-x^2}dx$$?

Comment: Your series expansion only converges on a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ and so I don't know if it would be useful for computing an integral on all of $\mathbb R$

Comment: I think you mean $p\to0^+$ not $t\to0^+$

Comment: For $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^{n}e^{-x^2}dx$ ... zero when $n$ odd, Gamma function when $n$ even.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(y) = PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2 + (x+2)y}}{x+2} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$ Then $$f'(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 + (x+2)y} \, \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\pi} e^{y^2/4 + 2y}$$ so $$f(y) = \frac{\pi}{e^4} \mathrm{erfi}(2 + y/2) + C$$ for some constant $C$. Since $PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(x+2)^2}}{x+2} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$ it follows that $f(-4) = 0$ so $C = 0$.

Now set $y=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much but why $PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(x+2)^2}}{x+2} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$

Comment: So, you solved the question **given** $\mathrm{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$.  This may, indeed, be the OP's question, if that PV had been done in his textbook just before this problem.  But Ellen has asked about this, so I guess that was not the case.

Comment: @EllenEllen $e^{-x^2}/x$ is odd so PV $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^2}/x \, \mathrm{d}x$ is zero. The same argument for $e^{-(x+2)^2}/(x+2)$.

Comment: @user690643 thanks! Now i understand all things !+) nice solution 